# When using CSS, how can I prevent my DIVs from overlapping when I shrink my browser?

Tags: html, css

I'm new here, so please don't eat me alive. This place is intimidating.

Anyway, I'm putting together an index.php file using HTML and CSS. It looks great - except that when my browser gets really small, my DIVs will run into each other. Including a photo below, along with my CSS and HTML code.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!!

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/chrisbclark/3naymjh3/

Picture of the overlap I'm trying to fix:

[image]

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}



body {
    line-height: 1;
    background: url("bk.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
}

.container{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow: auto;

}
#head_wrap{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    /* height of header */
    height:auto;
    /* end height of header */
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:4px;
    /* thickness of long red line */
    border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    overflow: auto;
    /* end thickness of long red line */

}
#header{
    overflow: auto;

}
#form1{
    float:right;
    padding:10px;
}

.centered{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    opacity: 0.8;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
#loginform{
    padding:20px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #E7E7E7;
}

p {
    color:#000000
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>snostream</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style2.css" media="all">
    </head>


<body>
    <!--container starts-->
<div class="container">
        <!-- begin head wrap -->
        <div id="head_wrap">
            <!-- begin header -->
            <div id="header">
            <img src="images/logo.png">
            <form method="post" action="" id="form1">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="********">
                <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Login">
            </form>
            </div>
            <!-- end header -->
        </div>
        <!-- head wrap ends here -->

        <!--- main body --->

</div>

    <!--container ends-->
<div class="centered" id="loginform">
    <div id="thebox">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table>
            <p>
            <h2>Registration:</h2>
            <br><br>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="u_name">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="u_email">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Choose Password:</td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="u_pass" 
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Select Gender:</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="u_gender">
                        <option>Select a Gender</option>
                        <option>Male</option>
                        <option>Female</option>
                    </select>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Select Network:</td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="u_network">
                        <option>Select a Network</option>
                        <option>North Carolina</option>
                        <option>South Carolina</option>
                        <option>New York</option>
                        <option>California</option>
                    </select>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Birthday:</td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="date" name="u_birthday">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                    </td>   
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                    <center><br><br><button name="sign_up">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </p>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you put your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: **Don't use absolute positioning**.  Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: You must read about "responsive design" to let your website ready for mobile devices (and also shrink browsers). If you want to test your website behaviour on different screens, I suggest you [troy.labs](http://troy.labs.daum.net/).

Comment: Again - I'm new here, so here is my attempt at placing the code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chrisbclark/3naymjh3/

Answer (score 2):

set width according to percentages instead of points and pixels.

The total width span should not exceed 100% for a total row span.
What do i mean by here is that if 3 DIV lie in the same row, their width sum should be 100% 
Example: DIV#1: 40%, DIV#2: 20%, DIV#3: you guessed it 40%.

Another way to control this is that never ever use position: relative, its a eye throw away only pertaining to your browser, your web will work differently on each device.